# PHP - function return an array after array_push

Tags: php, arrays, function, return, array-push

Why is 'the array pushed element' not echoed?

```
function dofoo1() {  

    $array = array("1aaa", "2bbbb", "3cccc");  
    $count = '######';  
    $array1 = array_push($array, $count);  

    return $array1;  
}  

$foo1 = dofoo1();  
echo $foo1[3];
```

Answer (score 6):

No need to assign `array_push` to a variable.

```
function dofoo1() {

    $array = array("1aaa", "2bbbb", "3cccc");  
    $count = '######';  
    array_push($array, $count);  

    return $array;  
}  


$foo1 = dofoo1();  
echo $foo1[3];
```

Comment: It's different from one in javascript. Gracias!

Comment: @Latestarter De nada :)

Answer (score 2):

You can simply use array merge

```
function dofoo1() {  
  $array = array("1aaa", "2bbbb", "3cccc");  
  $count = '######';  
  
  return array_merge($array, array($count));  
}  

$foo1 = dofoo1();  
echo $foo1[3];
```

Answer (score 1):

[`array_push()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-push.php) Returns the new number of elements in the array.

So, You should return the array itself in which you have pushed,

Change,

```
return $array1;
```

to

```
return $array;
```

Answer (score 1):

As described in the [php docs](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-push.php) `array_push()` **alters the given array** and returns only the number of elements. 
Therefore you have to return `$array` instead of `$array1`.

If you just want to **add one element**, it is even better to **avoid `array_push()`** and use `$array[] = $count;` instead.
This usage is **recommended in the [docs](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-push.php)** of `array_push()`.

So your code should look like this:

```
function dofoo1() {  
  $array = array("1aaa", "2bbbb", "3cccc");  
  $count = '######';  
  $array[] = $count;  

  return $array;  
}  

$foo1 = dofoo1();  
echo $foo1[3];
```